# Suggestions on a simple splittest architecture

Tags: playframework, split, ab-testing, abtest

I'm pretty new with the Play framework.
I wanna make a simple splittest framework for my web solution, but I'm not quite sure how I would go about creating one. I've read pretty much all the documentation, and I have not seen anything particularly relevant.

My idea of a splittest is obviously making users hit various different pages, and then keeping statistics of how users are interacting on each of them.

I don't need an in-depth answer, mostly just pointers and ideas as how it could be done with Play.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, I found this through a google search:
[Anyone got any good strategies for A/B testing with the Play Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753016/anyone-got-any-good-strategies-for-a-b-testing-with-the-play-framework)

Oddly enough I didn't find it when searching here on stackoverflow.

Now I have something to work with.